# Second moment of ranks

Tags: pr.probability, expectation

Suppose vector $R$ is a random permutation of the integers
1 through $n$ such that 
$$
\mathcal{P}\left(R_i = 1\right) = \pi_i,
$$
for given vector of probabilities $\pi$. 
Moreover, assume a 'proportional' model for higher values:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}\left(R_i = 2\right) &= \sum_{j \ne i} \frac{\pi_j}{1 - \pi_j} \pi_i,\\
\mathcal{P}\left(R_i = 3\right) &= \sum_{j \ne i \ne k,j \ne k} \frac{\pi_j}{1 - \pi_j} \frac{\pi_k}{1 - \pi_j - \pi_k}\pi_i,
\end{align}
and so on. Furthermore, these are a consequence of a kind of 'proportionality' of the probabilities, wherein:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}\left(R_i = 2 \left| R_j = 1\right.\right) &= \frac{\pi_j}{1 - \pi_j} \pi_i,\\
\mathcal{P}\left(R_i = 3 \left| R_j = 1, R_k = 2\right.\right) &= 
\frac{\pi_j}{1 - \pi_j} \frac{\pi_k}{1 - \pi_j - \pi_k}\pi_i,
\end{align}
and so on.

I am interested in the moments of $R$, in particular the second moment, $E\left[R_i R_j\right]$. 
How can this be computed?

For the first moment of $R$, I got lucky: tried a few simple cases, noticed a pattern and proved it
by induction. This is not so easy for higher order moments, and I was hoping there is a more elegant
approach.

*Note:* For more background,
the vector $R$ can arise as the vector of ranks of $n$ independent Exponential random variables.
And this is all somehow related to the soft-max.

I have computed the expectation for a few simple cases, but it has not yielded a pattern. For the case of $i=j$, and small values of $n$:
\begin{align}
(n = 1)\, E\left[R_1^2\right] &= 1,\\
(n = 2)\, E\left[R_1^2\right] &= 4 - 3 \pi_1,\\
(n = 3)\, E\left[R_1^2\right] &= 5 - 2 \pi_1 \left(\frac{1}{\pi_1 + \pi_2} + \frac{1}{\pi_1 + \pi_3}\right) +4 \left(1 - \pi_1\right) - 3 \pi_1 \left(\frac{\pi_2}{1 - \pi_2} + \frac{\pi_3}{1 - \pi_3}\right), ...
\end{align}
Again this was not terribly helpful. We should see $E\left[R_i^2\right] \rightarrow n^2$ as $\pi_i \rightarrow 0$, and $E\left[R_i^2\right] \rightarrow 1$ as $\pi_i \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: do you also expect that $\mathcal{P}(R_i=2|R_j=1)=\frac{\pi_j\pi_i}{1 - \pi_j}$?

Comment: @fedor-petrov : ah, yes, I was inprecise. The probabilities follow a kind of 'proportional' law that is related to the soft-max function, and indeed satisfy the relation above.